# Cant Get POST Unit Test To Update Data Working

Tags: django, selenium, django-forms, tdd

I am trying to make a unit test in Selenium to check that my POST works on my user profile page (users are able to update their profile information). My problem is that I cant get it to work (I cant get the unit test to update the users email) - I've tried many things but cant get it right.

This test returns: AssertionError: 'user@example.com' != 'update@example.com'

views.py

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
           u_form.save()
           p_form.save()
           messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated')
           return redirect('update_profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/update_profile.html', context)
```

form.py

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

test.py

```
def test_update_works(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', email='user@example.com')
        self.client.force_login(user)
        self.client.post('/profile/update_profile',{'email': 'updated@example.com'},)
        self.assertEqual(user.email, 'updated@example.com')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the old user information in memory, before the update was done. You need to "refresh" your user information from the database and then check against the new email.

```
def test_update_works(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', email='user@example.com')
    self.client.force_login(user)
    self.client.post('/profile/update_profile',{'email': 'updated@example.com'},)
    user.refresh_from_db() # here you get the latest info
    self.assertEqual(user.email, 'updated@example.com')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea I had to refresh the db.

Comment: You are refreshing the `user` variable that you already have in memory, not the db. The db has the latest value updated by the `update_profile` view.